# Nuxt v3: How does one access the package.json variables?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

With Nuxt v2 you could access the process environment variables using `process.env.npm_package_name`, for example. You still can in Nuxt v3, but it has to be wrapped in a `publicRuntimeConfig()`.

This is how I have gone about it:

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "nuxt-example-app",
  "displayName": "Nuxt v3 Example App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "This is an app primarily to showcase my skills with Nuxt, and other web orientated implementations.",
  .
  .
  .
}
```

`nuxt.config.ts`

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    NPM_PACKAGE_NAME: process.env.npm_package_name,
    NPM_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION: process.env.npm_package_description
  },
  .
  .
  .
});
```

`app.vue`

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const config = useRuntimeConfig();
useHead({
  title: config.NPM_PACKAGE_NAME || '',
  meta: [
    { name: 'description', content: config.NPM_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION || '' }
  ]
});
</script>
```

`config.NPM_PACKAGE_NAME` is defined, but `config.NPM_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION` is not. `process.env.npm_package_description` worked in Nuxt v2, why not now?

The NPM documentation states:

> The package.json fields are tacked onto the npm_package_ prefix. So, for instance, if you had `{"name":"foo", "version":"1.2.5"}` in your package.json file, then your package scripts would have the `npm_package_name` environment variable set to "foo", and the `npm_package_version` set to "1.2.5". You can access these variables in your code with `process.env.npm_package_name` and `process.env.npm_package_version`, and so on for other fields.

([source](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#packagejson-vars))

Running `process.env` on the debug console does not even show `npm_package_name` in the object, let alone `npm_package_description`.

Comment: I suppose that you can import ./package.json in nuxt.config.ts and use any data from it directly.

Comment: lol! I hadn't even thought of that. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer, but an alternative solution that [Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74111233/nuxt-v3-how-does-one-access-the-package-json-variables#comment130850400_74111233) has pointed out, is you can just import the `package.json` into `nuxt.config.ts`.

`nuxt.config.ts`

```
import packageJSON from './package.json';

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    head: {
      title: packageJSON.name || '',
      charset: 'utf-8',
      viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1',
      meta: [
        { name: 'description', content: packageJSON.description || '' }
      ]
    }
  },
  .
  .
  .
});
```

Comment: Does it work when you build it too?

Comment: Yup, looks like it does  Just built and previewed